# How do I undo deleting my bluetooth device from my macbook bluetooth device list?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I accidentally deleted my Bluetooth speakers from my MacBook's devices list. Now it will not show up again. How can I get it to show up again so I can reconnect it?

Answer (score 5):

Most Bluetooth speakers have a pairing routine that will usually be initiated right after turning on, or by keeping the power / pair / connect / play button pressed for a while —which specific button will depend on your speaker make and model; either explore a bit, or find the manual.

Answer (score 3):

In System Preferences under 'Bluetooth', try turning Bluetooth off and then on again. Under 'Devices' your Mac should start discovering Bluetooth devices within range (make sure you are within range of your speakers when you do this).

If that doesn't work, make sure your speakers are connected to power or that their batteries are new/charged.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem as you. If you have wireless headphones what you want to do is:

1. Make sure you turn off your headphones
2. Turn off all bluetooth devices
3. If it is a headphone like Beats Solo 3 you want to hold the power button for about 4 secs.
4. Turn your bluetooth device back on, and on your Mac and it should show up for pairing under devices.

Comment: Saved me day.... much thx.